# merge [gnu-screen] and [screen]

Tags: support, tags, merge

AFAICT, [screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/screen) and [gnu-screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) cover the same topic, GNU Screen. Can we please merge them?

[screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/screen) has more followers and is the simpler name, so I suggest keeping that. But [gnu-screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) is also fine if "screen" seems too generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/screen) does seem too generic. I'm merging [screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/screen) into [gnu-screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen).

I did see a few questions under that tag that weren't about GNU screen, but apparently about the user's physical display. Any such questions that remain should have that tag removed. I think I got them all, but it would be helpful for another person or two to look over the list of questions and retag any that might need it.